# how to fix this cudnn and torch error

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch, cudnn

I run the torch `./test.sh`,and get error like these:

```
Found Environment variable CUDNN_PATH = /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6
/home/whj/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/whj/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/ffi.lua:1618: These bindings are for CUDNN 5.x (5005 <= cudnn.version > 6000) , while the loaded CuDNN is version: 6020  
Are you using an older or newer version of CuDNN?
```

My cuda is 8.0 and already move libcudnn.so.6 into its folder, how can I fix error above. 
At the beginning, it just reports error like couldn't find libcudnn.so.6, no such file etc, and then I add the `export CUDNN_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6$CUDNN_PATH"` in /.bashrc and reboot, it change to error above.

Comment: it should be `export CUDNN_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6:$CUDNN_PATH"` (you forgot a `:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason-- cuda-8.0 can't fit cudnn.so.6